# Storing long string resources in a Blackberry application

Tags: string, blackberry, resources

What's the best way to store a very long string resource for a Blackberry app? Just using a static final variable somewhere is ugly because this is a huge 100 line string, and Java has no multi-line string syntax. Should I just stick it in a text file and bundle that with my app, or is there an accepted way to do this?

Comment: It depends on (1) size and (2) purpose. Please provice further details on what is the min/average/max size and what are you going  to do with the string within the app.

Comment: @Arhimed It's about 100 lines of HTML that is the disclaimer for the app. We're just rendering it on screen the first time the user uses the app.

Comment: according to the purpose you don't need to keep it for the entire app session, so no need to keep it in a static final field. read it from resources as suggested below just in the time it is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse with the Blackberry plugin, it has a Resource editor that you can use to add string resources to a Blackberry project.  You can then load the strings at runtime when needed using the `StringProvider` class.

Comment: +1 For resource files. With the added benefit this is where you would normally need the info to be for localizing.

Comment: Is there any limit to the size of strings you can use in this way?

Comment: @jjoelson: it should definitely be Ok fro a 100 lines of HTML file.